# Solving the view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: python, django

I am getting the error below

Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/place_order/
Django Version: 3.1

```
Exception Value:    
The view orders.views.place_order didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

This is a snippet of my `views.py` file

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print('we are here checking if the form is valid')
        data = Order()
        data.user = current_user
        data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        data.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
        data.address_line_2 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_2']
        data.country = form.cleaned_data['country']
        data.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
        data.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
        data.order_note = form.cleaned_data['order_note']
        data.order_total = grand_total
        data.tax =tax
        data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        data.save()
        return redirect('checkout')
else:    
    return redirect('checkout')
```

Comment: form.is_valid() returns False I guess, and there is no explicit return after the (2nd) if statement. Python returns None if there is no explicit return in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue. Apparently if there is an error / typo in the HTML form code it will throw the error "didn't return an HttpResponse object". There was nothing wrong with the view.

Answer (score 0):

Your view should return a response also if the form is not valid, you can raise an exception:

```py
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = OrderForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print('we are here checking if the form is valid')
        data = Order()
        data.user = current_user
        data.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        data.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        data.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        data.email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        data.address_line_1 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_1']
        data.address_line_2 = form.cleaned_data['address_line_2']
        data.country = form.cleaned_data['country']
        data.state = form.cleaned_data['state']
        data.city = form.cleaned_data['city']
        data.order_note = form.cleaned_data['order_note']
        data.order_total = grand_total
        data.tax =tax
        data.ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
        data.save()
        return redirect('checkout')
    else:
        raise BadRequest() # Or do whatever makes sense to you
else:    
    return redirect('checkout')
```